# Cannot browse other Workstation

Tags: windows-xp, networking

I have setup a LAN on two comps running WinXP pro each with "Setup a home or small office network" wizard. Comp which also has internet connection (Internet Connection Sharing, ICS is enabled for the network) can browse another comp's shared folder but the other comp cannot browse shared folders of the first comp.

IP for first comp is 192.168.0.1 and other in the same subnet is assigned 192.168.xx.xx by DHCP.

Pls help me resolve this.

Regards,
rseni.

Comment: Is your firewall/anti virus allowing incoming connections? Which security software do you have installed?

Comment: Hy I solved it. Sorry for this very late update. This thread can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you dont have a performance tweak to disable Computer Browser Services.

Run> Services.msc  > Computer browser> Auto, started

Of course Sharing must be enabled
Normally I enable this by run> netsetup (enter)